# Import multiple instances of a class differed by parameter value in MEF

Tags: .net, mef

I would like to export from one type two its different instances that differ in parameters that were passed to their constructors.

To be more specific:

```
interface IA {
 string P { get; }
}

[Export(typeof(IA))]
[ExportMetadata("p", "1")]
[ExportMetadata("p", "2")]
class A : IA {

 [ImportingConstructor]
 public A( string p ) {
  this.P = p;
 }

 public string P { get; set; }
}
```

I would like, when importing a collection of `IA`'s, get two instances of `A` that were instantiated with different values of constructor parameter `p` - one with `1` and other with `2` (I want these parameters to be taken from export metadata).

Is it possible to archieve this in MEF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a property export work for your scenario?

```
class A : IA
{
    public A(string p) { P = p; }
    public string P { get; set; }
}

class AExports
{
    [Export(typeof(IA))]
    [ExportMetadata("p", "1")]
    public IA A1
    {
        get { return new A("1"); }
    }

    [Export(typeof(IA))]
    [ExportMetadata("p", "2")]
    public IA A2
    {
        get { return new A("2"); }
    }
}
```